# Can I initialize a thread that is asleep in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading

I'm messing around with threads in ruby and I was trying to see what would happen if I did something like this

```
x = 0
a = Thread.new{ x += 1 while true }
b = Thread.new{ x -= 1 while true }
```

but I want `a` and `b` to start at the same time. Can I initialize `a` and `b` both as sleeping threads and awake them at the same time? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In ruby, you can't create an asleep thread, but a thread can put itself into sleep until some other thread wakes it up.

```
x = 0
a = Thread.new{ Thread.stop; x += 1 while true }
b = Thread.new{ Thread.stop; x -= 1 while true }

a.run
b.run
```

Comment: This works thank you! Interestingly enough `x` stays at `0`. I'm surprised that `a.run` and `b.run` on different lines start the thread at the same time whereas `[a,b].each(&:run)` did not.

Comment: Interestingly I ran this snippet of code in irb and found that `x` rockets until about 150_000_000, and then it starts go up and down randomly. P.S. I'm on a Mac.

Comment: If you run it in `irb` it will do that because `a` runs before `b`, but if you run it as a `.rb` with `ruby` it seems to stay flat.

Comment: Here is a [link](https://github.com/snood1205/SUMMER2016/raw/master/CMPSC121/output.txt) to an output file I wrote to, if anyone is interested with the values of `x`.

Comment: Maybe, but I ran with a little twist, `a.run; b.run`. I think I would never fires multiple threads that accesses shared memory, and expect them to run evenly.

Comment: I was trying to see how bad it was to use shared memory between threads which is obviously an awful idea and how ruby distributed thread memory.

Comment: I'm not sure what makes this any more 'at the same time' than your original example though. You still had to do `a.run` followed by `b.run`.  Putting them both on the same line with a semi-colon doesn't change anything.  It won't necessarily be any more 'at the same time' than your original example of creating one thread that immediately starts followed by another that immediately starts. It's essentially the same thing.

Comment: There are more complicated things you could do having both threads wait on a shared concurency-safe mutex/monitor. But I still don't think it will do what you want. "At the same time" doesn't really mean anything when doing concurrent programming, there's essentially no way to have two things happen "at the same time" literally. But you can use various concurrent synchronization constructs to make one thing happen _only after_ another thing has happened.

Comment: An accident of MRI implementation may make it difficult (or even impossible?) to produce the evidence of 'badness' you are looking for. MRI is 'not great' at concurrency, and this 'not greatness' will make it harder to demonstrate the error in that code. Try running under JRuby, I bet you'll see weirder results like you are looking for. It's not really about whether you use `a.run ; b.run` or `[a, b].each(&:run)` or even just your first example of two threads created running. Those things don't matter, if they appear to it's a coincidence or an accident of ruby interpreter implementation.